# Parameterized complex numbers in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy, complex-numbers

Consider the following Python code:

```
import sympy as sp

t = sp.symbols('t', real=True)

y = sp.parse_expr(input("y = "))
real_imag = y.as_real_imag()
print("Real:", real_imag[0])
print("Imaginary:", real_imag[1])
```

When the input to y variable is "t**2 + t*I", the output is:

```
Real: re(t)**2 - im(t)**2 - im(t)
Imaginary: 2*re(t)*im(t) + re(t)
```

Why the output is not like this?

```
Real: t**2
Imaginary: t
```

The input must be taken from the user, it is essential. And the output must be without re() and im() functions. Is there a way to do so?

Tried:

- re() and im() functions instead of as_real_imag(),
- sympify() instead of parse_expr(),
- simplify() and expand().
  But nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol that you create with `real=True` will not be used by `parse_expr` unless you pass it in:

```
In [11]: t = symbols('t', real=True)

In [12]: y = parse_expr('t**2 + I*t', local_dict={'t':t})

In [13]: y
Out[13]: 
 2      
t  + ⅈ⋅t

In [14]: y.as_real_imag()
Out[14]: 
⎛ 2   ⎞
⎝t , t⎠
```